# Starting the sentence with "as much as"

Tags: pronouns

Is this sentence correct:

> **As much as** transition or mere changes to one's life may facilitate one's lifestyle,it doesn't necessarily improve it.

??

Comment: What do you think is wrong?

Comment: "it" is singular, but you have a double antecedent, one of which is plural.

Comment: 'As much as' isn't the problem here, as Tim implies.

Answer (score 1):

Starting the sentence with "As much as" is fully acceptable. I have come across many such sentences during my quests through the realms of fiction. Although, I would replace "it doesn't" with "they don't" since the last subject i.e "mere changes" is in plural form & hence would require the use of a subject pronoun appropriate for plural subjects i.e. "they".

Comment: Hello, Rahul. The person asking the question could easily have checked online for examples. If she'd done this, and still had a problem, it would have been more suitable to post (with research shown) at that stage.

Comment: My answer was given in response to an unedited version of the question which was "Can 'as much as' be used at the start of a sentence?" The question was edited after I had given my answer.

Comment: I posted my comment before she amended it. I'm saying that ELU policy is to wait for a question to be brought up to the required standards before giving an answer that the OP might well have gone a long way towards finding out for themselves. Look at how @deadrat responds in a comment.